# Checking dimensions of a table

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how I check the dimensions of a table with `R` rows, containing `C` entries.

The example pattern file, `Pattern file.txt`, contains a valid pattern.

```
10   10    50

        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue
       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red
        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue
       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red
        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue
       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red
        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue
       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red
        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue
       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red       blue        red
```

- The first line contains three integers, `R`, `C`, and `T`, representing the number of rows, the number of columns, and the tile size.
- There are `R` rows in the file.
- There are `C` colors listed in each row, separated by spaces

Comment: What does tile size mean in pattern.txt?

Comment: this is for a project. the tilesize is used to to draw tiles but that can be disregarded as it is not used for the dimension of the table

Comment: so what is the question? the dimensions of the tables are `R` and `C`

Comment: yes and how do i make sure that the table contains the correct amount of rows which is R in the first line and the correct amount of columns which is C in the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finding how many rows are in the file is easy:

```
f = open('somefile.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

print len(lines)
```

Minus the first line in your case

Now if you want to find how many rows there are you can for loop through the 
line and count the number of spaces and subtract that from the total or in this case I think that the number of spaces should equal the number of words.

```
count = 0
for x in lines[0]:
  if(x == ' '):
    count+=1
print count
```

Also to note:

that if you don't have a perfect square of a file and you want to count each row then you have to do it like so:

```
count = 0
for x in lines:
   for y in x:
     if(x == ' ')
       count+=1
   print count
   count = 0
```

Comment: and how do I count the number of rows?

Comment: The first code area. I say it in my first `print len(lines)` -- `lines` is an array were each element is a row. Don't forget to check mark(right under the up down arrow next to my post) the answer if you like it

Comment: can i email you about my other questions? this is for a project. I am a comp science major

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first line values as a reference to check if you table has the right dimensions.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    file = f.readlines()

for line in file:
    if line == file[0]:
        first_line = line.split()
        rows_nbr = int(first_line[0])
        columns_nbr = int(first_line[1])
        if len(file) - 2 != columns_nbr: # -2 here to skip the first two lines of the file
            print 'Incorrect column number !'
            break
    elif line == file[1]:
        continue
    else:
        current = line.split()
        if len(current) != rows_nbr:
            print 'Incorrect row number !'
            break
```